# Catch android's back button press event when showint a dialog/spinner's list?

Tags: android, button, dialog, back

I need to capture the event when my app is showing a dialog and i press the device's back button.

Well it is not definetly a dialog. It is a dropdown list for my spinner.

I tryed:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    {

    Toast myToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "back putton pressed", 1);
    myToast.show();

    }

    // Call super code so we dont limit default interaction
    super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

    return true;
}
```

Not worked.

I also tryed:

```
public void onBackPressed()
{


    Toast myToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "back putton pressed", 1);
    myToast.show();

}
```

I even tryed this with overriding.
So none of the above sollutions are worked for me. I found both of these on stackoverflow but for some reason they are not working for me.
Of course they work when there is now dialog showing, but when do... they are not run.

Any ideas ?

So my

Comment: what didn't worked with first code snippet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
 if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
{

    Toast myToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "back putton pressed", 1);
   myToast.show();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Why are you copying the same code if i marked its not working?

Comment: return true should be inside the KEYCODE_BACK

Answer (score 3):

A general way to detect if a dialog has been canceled (back button pressed) is to implement OnCancelListener, not really sure if it works on spinners though!

Answer (score 2):

see this

```
@Override 
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        //Handle the back button
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            //write your code...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you copying the same code if i marked its not working?

Answer (score 2):

try this...

```
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
    {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
        {

        Toast myToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "back putton pressed", 1);
        myToast.show();
   new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable{
    public void run(){
              finish();
        }
    }, 1000);
        }
    else{
        // Call super code so we dont limit default interaction
        super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I cannot wait 1 sec after the event :(

Answer (score 1):

try to use dismiss listener. a dialog can be dismissed by pressing a button or back key and using this listener you can know if user has pressed a button or back key (you can listen for onClick listener on your dialog to catch dialog's button' click).

Comment: Its a spinners dropdown menu how can i add dismiss listener to it ?